# Unexpected results creating an album (group) on iOS8 using ALAssetsLibrary framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

Apple is encouraging us to use the new PhotosFramework to interact with the camera roll in iOS8. But says nothing about AssetsLibraryFramework not working on iOS8.

So I'm using my pre-existing AssetsLibraryFramework code to do get the list of video ALAssets from the user's camera roll and display it. This works...still.

But when I try to create an album (group) using this AssetsLibraryFramework method:

```
- (void)addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:(NSString *)name
                    resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryGroupResultBlock)resultBlock
                   failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

Where resultBlock looks like this:

```
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryGroupResultBlock)(ALAssetsGroup *group));
```

The resultBlock is called with a nil group. The docs say that the group will be nil for a name collision, but there's no other album with the specified name. Definitely not a name collision.

I'm trying to determine if this is an error on my part, or evidence that ALAssetsLibrary cannot be trusted on iOS8 and I need to upgrade to PhotosFramework.

Are there other things that could cause the group to be nil? Is this method just not supported on iOS8?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What if you create it using PhotosFramework.

Comment: I'm sure that PhotosFramework allows you to create albums. This question is about (1) are there reasons other than name collision that can cause group to be nil in the example I describe and (2) is there documentation that states that ALAssetsLibrary or a subset of its API is not viable on iOS8.